# fill UIWebView with local "loading" image before internet content

Tags: delegates, uiwebview, loading, local

I have a **UITableView** with **header as a uiwebview** (320*44px) for **pub content**. I wonder how to show some local content image or a background color or whatever **before the content get loaded** from the web ??

*(**goal**: eleminate the white default background for not-loaded uiwebview banner)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//i assume ur webview object name as webView;

//i assume u were use delegate to ur webview by specifing after creating the webview like

webView.delegate=self;

//dont forget to in .h file @interface urViewController : vijayviewController<UIWebViewDelegate> { <UIWebViewDelegate> is matter.

UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:webView.bounds];

[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vijay.png"]];//image size should ur specification 320*44px

[imageView setTag:55];


[webView addSubview:imageView];

[imageView release];


//to remove image

//  [[webView viewWithTag:55] removeFromSuperview];


  - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{



    [[webView viewWithTag:55] removeFromSuperview];

   }
```